# What does ICX do for 605.mcf_s of SPEC2017?

Tags: c, gcc, benchmarking, compiler-optimization, icx

Recently I'm working on optimizing GCC for SPEC2017. And I found out that ICX runs two times faster on 605.mcf_s than GCC.

After a period of research, I've found that ICX has done a few things: fully unfold the `node` structure and compress the `arc` structure from 72 bytes to 32 bytes(or 20 bytes at some situation). These optimizations were shown in the wiki of GCC as well (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GCCSpec2017/mcf).

So I integrated these two optimizations into GCC, but after doing that, I found that there is still a big gap with ICX. So ICX must have made other optimizations that were more useful. I would like to ask if you know what else ICX has done to achieve such high efficiency?

Here are environment and compile options of running it.

> OS: Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64
>
> CPU and Memory: i9-12900KF 32GB
>
> GCC version: 12.3.0
>
> ICX version: 2023.2.0
>
> Benchmark: 605.mcf_s Base Intspeed

```
# compile options:
# GCC:
gcc -flto -O3 -mavx2

# ICX:
icx -flto -O3 -xavx2 -qopt-mem-layout-trans=4
```

##### Scores of 605.mcf_s:

GCC Original: 13.9

GCC Optimized: 16.9

ICX: 29.5

If you have any ideas to share, I'll be grateful. :)

Comment: I don't suppose `-march=native` / `-march=alderlake` to set `-mtune` makes any difference?  Seems odd to just use the default generic tuning, though, if you have a specific CPU in mind.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't bring any efficiency. So I didn't add that option here.